Add TermColumn to a SharePoint List using Graph 5.49.0 Should be supported now
Using "Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.49.0"
 var requestBody = new ColumnDefinition
 {
     Name = "DocumentType", Id = "fd18629e-47c3-4e63-9b26-4feb9f4ca9ef",
     Description = "Document Type", ColumnGroup = "Custom Columns", DisplayName = "Document Type",
     EnforceUniqueValues = false,
     Hidden = false,
     Indexed = true,
     Term = new TermColumn
     {
         OdataType = "microsoft.graph.termColumn",
         TermSet = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.TermStore.Set() { Id = "729779b3-b4f1-40d1-8139-8f5e8f6cc61e" },
         AllowMultipleValues = false, ShowFullyQualifiedName = false,
         ParentTerm = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.TermStore.Term  { Id = "db0ff271-5bb9-4a76-a98c-902bbfb2e38d" }                    
     },
 };           
 Console.WriteLine($"Creating Column {requestBody.Name} in List DPC Documents"); 
 try
 {
     var result = await _graphClient.Sites[projectSite.Id].Lists["DPC Documents"].Columns.PostAsync(requestBody);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }

I expected a "SspId" property and assumed it is the same as "Microsoft.Graph.Models.TermStore.Term"
I keep getting error "Invalid Request"
Is it still not supported by Graph? The code seams simple.
Thank you.

Does this answer your question? Create a site term column with graph API
